# discord.py send message at a specific hour and date

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm working on a bot to facilitate some of the things we do on hand in my team. With that I started to create some tasks that are running well, I need to create a notification that will run from Monday to Friday at 16, I saw some blogs and I tried to apply only without success, today this is my code and the function I want to call is called "LEMBRAR()", with that I wanted to know what options I have to be running this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from BotGooBee.Humor import GooBee

hora = '16:00'
diasSemanas = 'seg-sex'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot online')

@client.command()
async def limpar(ctx, amount=100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command()
async def feliz(ctx):
    GooBee(1).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | FELIZ')
    

@client.command()
async def normal(ctx):
    GooBee(2).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | NORMAL')

@client.command()
async def irritado(ctx):
    GooBee(3).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | IRRITADO')


async def lembrar():
    print('hello')
    channel = client.get_channel(id_channel)
    await channel.send('hello')
    
client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the datetime module like this, to get the current time, then check if the time is correct then run the function.

```
import datetime

# Gets the weekday and returns a number: 0 for monday : 6 for sunday
print(datetime.datetime.today().weekday())

# Gets the current time
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())
```

Then if it is the right day and time you can run the function.

Comment: after `.time()` you can put `.hour` to only get the hour.

Answer (score 0):

for those who have doubts I managed to make this alert, following the tip above so I added a condition at the end bot.loop.create_task (my_def ())

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from BotGooBee.Humor import GooBee
import asyncio
import json
import random
import datetime

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
with open('frases.json', 'r') as json_file:
            dados = json.load(json_file)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot online')

@bot.command()
async def limpar(ctx, amount=100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')

@bot.command()
async def feliz(ctx):
    GooBee(1).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | FELIZ')
    

@bot.command()
async def normal(ctx):
    GooBee(2).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | NORMAL')

@bot.command()
async def irritado(ctx):
    GooBee(3).AtualizarHumor()
    await ctx.send('Humor alterado | IRRITADO')
#funcao que faz o alerta da mensagem
async def AlerteHumor():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        print('alerta humor')
        hora = int(datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H"))
        minutos = int(datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%M"))
        if hora == 16 and minutos <= 59:
            channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            await channel.send(dados[f'{random.randrange(1,5)}'])
        await asyncio.sleep(3600)

bot.loop.create_task(AlerteHumor())
bot.run(token)
```